# Why aren't sub-categories nested after creating post in the WP Admin?

Tags: categories, wp-admin

I have several sub-categories set up. Everything displays properly as far as nesting (see below) when creating a new post.

> Category 1
>
> --Sub Category 1
>
> --Sub Category 2
>
> --Sub Category 3
>
> Category 2
>
> etc

After I select a sub-category, then go back and edit a post, the sub category that I check shows up like this (note how it's not nested under Category 1):

> (checkmark) Sub Category 2
>
> Category 1
>
> --Sub Category 1
>
> --Sub Category 3
>
> Category 2
>
> etc

Is this a bug in WordPress 3.1.2? Can someone tell me how to fix it? I don't remember it doing this when I was running 3.0.5 (but there's a chance it could have).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This "feature" has been in WP for quite a while.

You can disable it by installing this small plugin:

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/category-checklist-tree/

Comment: Very nice dude. This worked perfectly!

Comment: Does anyone know if this is still the best way to remove this 'feature'?

Comment: This plugin is over 4 years old and can't be reliably used because as of today it has not been tested with the latest 191 major and minor wordpress versions.

Comment: True, but the plugin only really adds 3 lines of code that are important. And these still work flawlessly. See my new answer for more info.

Answer (score 3):

It was mentioned that scribu's plugin hasn't been updated in four years. However, the plugin is fairly simple and the most important part is this:

```
add_filter( 'wp_terms_checklist_args', function( $args ) {
  $args['checked_ontop'] = false;

  return $args;
} );
```

That's what the plugin mainly does — plus some JavaScript to scroll to the first category checkbox that is checked. But that's just for convenience.

Comment: Thanks @swissspidy I don't like using plugins for such tasks, and it worked.